# WCF (Can't add Quartz in WCF Project)

Tags: c#, wcf, quartz.net

(As I'm new to WCF)
I want to add Quartz in Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) project.
And I also wants to know that which file or method execute first after run the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using Quartz, I used C# Timer.
The Timer class in C# represents a Timer control that executes a code block at a specified interval of time repeatedly.

//Timer Class

```
public class FileJob
{
    private System.Timers.Timer ProcessTimer;
    
    public void Start()
    {
        try
        {
            ProcessTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            ProcessTimer.AutoReset = true;
            ProcessTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(ProcessTimer_Elapsed);
            ProcessTimer.Interval = 300000; //5 minutes
            ProcessTimer.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }
    }

    private void ProcessTimer_Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UploadFile();
    }
}
```

Global.asax.cs

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileJob obj = new FileJob();
        obj.Start();
    }
}
```